# Best Method for Tracking Processes

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker, process

At my consulting company, we use some very expensive simulation software. I need a means to monitor the usage of these applications/processes (in the background, using C#). The idea is that when someone runs a particular application, they are prompted to enter the job name. Then, when they close the program, the amount of time they used it is sent to a database residing on the network. This way we can recoup the costs of the software by charging our clients on a $/min basis. Aside from the prompt, the program must be nearly invisible to users.

I have thought of a few ways of doing this, but I'm not sure what's best:

1. Have a program that runs on startup, with only a tray icon. I suppose then I would have to have a backgroundworker monitoring the processes continuously, perhaps sleeping the thread, and checking the processes every 5 minutes or so.
2. Use something like Quartz.net, on startup and with a tray icon. If this is even applicable on a minute-by-minute basis. I am not very familiar with Quartz.net, but from my research it looks maybe do-able.
3. Use some kind of Windows Service. This one I am least familiar with.

Which method would be most fruitful? Thanks

Comment: Any decent programmer would disable your tracker in a heartbeat.

Comment: Why prompt for a name?  I would think you'd just code the apps to phone home and/or log their own statistics with no user intervention...

Comment: @LarsTech: why would a programmer want to disable it?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to monitor the use of this software at your own company, so that you know when your consultants use it and you can then bill that usage to your clients? It's a little unclear.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman It sounds like this tracker is used to charge the end user for the amount of time used on any program (or in this example, their simulation software).  So if someone disables it, they won't have to pay for it (or that part of it).  I'm not saying it's honest — just human nature.  This consulting company needs to re-think their business strategy.

Comment: Well, it's our company...  we are using the software. And we need to know how much we use it! We also have to prompt for a name in order to know which job the software is being used for.

Comment: "nearly invisible to users" made it sound like this was trying to be a little sneaky.  It was also unclear "where" this software was installed on.  Hence the confusion.

Comment: Nope, sorry. Nothing too covert here. Just trying to be user friendly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a simple C# program that upon execution collects the required information and start time.

Then by using the `Process` class you execute the simulation software.
Wait for the process to end using `WaitForExit()` and do whatever is needed with the execution time etc.

So essentially you end up with an application that simply collects the required information, launches the main application, waits for the application to end and does whatever is needed with the total execution time. As far as being invisible to the user, you could just minimize the main window ( which also acts as the form for collecting the needed info ) while waiting for the application to end.

Here is a small example of starting an executable within C#.

```
private void LaunchApp()
    {
        Process proc = new Process();
        /* we are going to assume wordpad is installed on workstation */

        /* collect needed info and time */


        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "Wordpad.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "SomeFile.txt";
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();


        /* App has ended. Now process execution time etc. */
    }
```

Comment: This sounds interesting--basically I would need to make a "program launcher" type program. This is one idea, though it is easily circumvented, by not starting the program through the launcher. Not sure if management would be 100% happy since it's not very hidden, and you would have to change people's habits of starting the program. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: You're welcome. A user could still by-pass your needs to log the job name by simply not interacting with the the dialog. In the meantime the simulation software is still running. With a launcher type solution I've proposed the only way to start the app is by entering the required information ( that is assuming they use the launcher app ). But you could help them change habits by removing the applications desktop and task bar, menu bar links and replacing them with links to the launcher app.